# Use a form field input to set an anythingSlider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I can't seem to figure out how to make a form input box such that when you click a submit button, the value of that input box is updating this slider

http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

`$('#myForm').click ( function() { $('#slider').anythingSlider(formVal); } )`

Comment: @User1159429 please see how your question looks now we have more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment and fixing your question, I think you mean

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myButton').click(function() { 
    $('#slider').anythingSlider($("#myField").val()); 
  })
});
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="myField" value="" />
<input type="button" id="myButton"/>
</form>
```

Comment: no, not homework. Im just trying to get a content slider working.

Answer (score 0):

Create an input box and a button in html body

```
<form>
  <input id='input1' name='input1' />
  <input type='button' value='Submit' id='submit' onclick='onSubmit()' />
</form>
```

Add this function to your javascript

```
function onSubmit() {
  formVal = document.getElementbyId('input1').value
}
```

For your case, use JQuery as

```
$document.ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var formval = $('$inpupt1').val();
    $('#slider').anythingSlider(formVal); 
  });
});
```

Comment: how would I incorporate that with the following code? What it does is when someone inputs a number into the box and hits "submit", my content slider will switch to that slide `$('#myForm').click (
    function() {
        $('#slider').anythingSlider(formVal);
    }
 );`